# Multidimensional array terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm writing some code that manages data stored in multidimensional arrays and a bit unsure of the correct terminology to use in my code comments, function and variable names etc.  Have browsed a few Wikipedia articles relating to arrays, matrices, linear algebra and the like, and the answers haven't leapt out at me....

- Is there a generalisation for N dimensional arrays for the terms "row" and "column" that would be used for 2 dimensional arrays.
- If I apply a single scalar index to a N dimensional array, I'm now addressing a "sub-array" of dimensionality N-1.  What is the correct term for this "sub-array"  (I'd started using sub-array, but this aint right as it's got an accepted meaning as describing an arbitrary subset of elements  within an array)

thanks.

Comment: Row and column work for arbitrary number of rows and columns, this is already a generalization.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about arrays and not multidimensional matrices, but perhaps this can help. If you fix an index of the elements of a multidimensional matrix, it is called a "slice".  So the rows would be the first slices, the columns the second slices and so forth.  I haven't heard a term applied for a "sub-multidimensional matrix". See Schläfli, L. (1852) Über die Resultante eine Systemes mehrerer algebraischer Gleichungen, Denkschr. Kaiserl. Akad. Wiss., Math.-Naturwiss. Klasse 4

Comment: thanks Paul, had already come across  the term "slice", but considered it ambiguous in my context due to it's widespread usage in the Python programming language to describe an indexing operation that can return an arbitrary sub-array (also in C++ STL valarray class)